# What is the difference between "vorangehen" and "vorausgehen" in terms of time?

Tags: english-to-german, difference, german-to-english

I have been having a very difficult time trying to figure out both the correct word usage and the difference between meanings concerning the two words "vorangehen" and "vorausgehen" when talking about "preceding" something timewise. Let me give a couple of example sentences.

1. *Dem Tsunami ging ein Erdbeben voraus.*
2. *Dem Tsunami ging ein Erdbeben voran.*
3. *Er ist mir als Chef in dieser Firma vorangegangen/vorausgegangen.* (He preceded me as boss in this firm.)

Do sentences 1 and 2 make sense, and if so, what is the difference? And, does sentence 3 make sense at all, and if not, how would such an idea be expressed?

Comment: "voran" tends to imply *precedence in space*, like a railway engine preceding the railway cars. "voraus" tends to imply *precedence in time*, e.g. lightning before thunder, perhaps even without any specific direction.

Comment: @KilianFoth So, "Die Lokomativ geht den Waggons voran; das erste Ereignis ist dem Zweiten vorausgegangen."? Also, wuerdest du "precedence in space" als "raeumliches Vorhergehen" uebersetzen? Danke fuer deine Hilfe!!!

Comment: Hmmm... "es geht voran" usually means "things are going forward", i.e. proceeding. I think "Dem Tsunami ging ein Erdbeben voraus" sounds right, but not "voran".

Answer (score 2):

Für Satz 3 würde ich eher sagen

> Er war vor mir Chef in dieser Firma (ugs.)

bzw.

> Er war mein Vorgänger als Geschäftsführer in diesem Unternehmen

(oder je nachdem *als Gesellschafter, geschäftsführender Direktor, kaufmännischer Leiter* usw.)

oder

> Vor mir war Herr ... hier Geschäftsführer (bzw. der Chef, ...)

oder

> Vor mir hatte er hier die Leitungsfunktion inne

oder

> Bevor ich die Leitung übernahm, wurde das Unternehmen von ihm geführt.

'Vorangegangen'/'vorausgegangen' wäre mit der Assoziation verbunden: Da er ja gegangen ist, vielleicht sogar gehen musste, werde ich, der ich ihm nachfolge, demnächst auch gehen (müssen). Das ist natürlich nicht gemeint, aber es schwingt als ein Nebenton mit.

Answer (score 1):

> Do sentences 1 and 2 make sense, and if so, what is the difference?

Yes, both of these sentences make sense and there's no difference.

> And, does sentence 3 make sense at all, and if not, how would such an idea be expressed?

Yes, the 3rd sentence makes also sense and *vorangegangen* / *vorausgegangen* can be used equally well to express the same english term *preceded*.